# render data inserted to collection in react component

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, render

My entire application is built on different react classes and displayed like this:

```
MainLayout = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="body">
        <Header />
        <main className="container">{this.props.content}</main>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

All my front-end is built in react classes like the one below:

```
InsertData = React.createClass({
    insertToCollection(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.message + " state med message");
        var content = Posts.find().fetch();
            Posts.insert({
                Place: $("post1").val(),
                Type: $("post2").val(),
                dateAdded: new Date(),
            });
    },

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            message: event.target.value
        })

        console.log(this.state + " mer state her");
        function insert(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("added stuff"); 
        }
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.insertToCollection}>
                    <input type='text' placeholder="Select a restaurant" className="input-field" 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} id="post1"/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder="What type of food they have" className="input-field" 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} id="post2"/>
                    <button className="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-block" onChange={this.insert}> Submit </button>
                </form>
                <DisplayData />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Insert data to my collection works fine. I would like to render the inserted data onto the page from the `<DisplayData />` component:

```
DisplayData = React.createClass({
    render(){
        var posts = Posts.find().fetch();
        var postList = posts.map(function(posts){
            return posts; 
        })
        return <p> Your collection </p>
    }
});
```

I'm rather stuck here, and not really sure how to iterate through the collection and render it in a list-structure for example. Here is my collection so far:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Posts.allow({
    insert: function(){
        return true; 
    }, 
    update : function(){
        return true; 
    },
    remove : function(){
        return true; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of how you can approach this: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/bwmAvJ

I'm not sure about the format of your `posts` collection, but assuming that it is just a regular array, for example `var posts = ['One', 'Two'];`, you can render the individual post as follows:

```
var DisplayData = React.createClass({
    render(){
        var posts = ['One', 'Two'];

        var renderPosts = posts.map(function(post, index) {
            return (
              <li key={index}>{post}</li>
            ); 
        });

        return (
          <div>
            <p> Your collection </p>
            <ul>
              {renderPosts}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Here is the full code from my codepen.

```
var InsertData = React.createClass({
    insertToCollection(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.message + " state med message");
        var content = Posts.find().fetch();
            Posts.insert({
                Place: $("post1").val(),
                Type: $("post2").val(),
                dateAdded: new Date(),
            });
    },

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            message: event.target.value
        })

        console.log(this.state + " mer state her");
        function insert(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("added stuff"); 
        }
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.insertToCollection}>
                    <input type='text' placeholder="Select a restaurant" className="input-field" 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} id="post1"/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder="What type of food they have" className="input-field" 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} id="post2"/>
                    <button className="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-block" onChange={this.insert}> Submit </button>
                </form>
                <DisplayData />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var DisplayData = React.createClass({
    render(){
        var posts = ['One', 'Two'];

        var renderPosts = posts.map(function(post, index) {
            return (
              <li key={index}>{post}</li>
            ); 
        });

        return (
          <div>
            <p> Your collection </p>
            <ul>
              {renderPosts}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
}); 


ReactDOM.render(
  <InsertData />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Steingrim, I've just updated my answer. Does it help?

Comment: Steingrim, I've just updated my answer as I initially missed the curly braces when rendering the `post` here: `<li key={index}>{post}</li>`. Would you like me to add anything to the above or does it answer your question.

Comment: no worries! i'm very greatfull for the answer. If you would like to assist me further the ReactDOM function outside the displaydata-class breaks the entire routing of my application. I will update my initial post to explain in more detail

Comment: Steingrim, if it is not related to rendering a collection (array), I suggest posting a new question.

Comment: the collection itself is not the main concern of my issue. My first priority is to display the users input below the input-filed as well as insterting them to a collection

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `posts` to your view component `DisplayData` as props, so in this case after you inserted a post, you should update your state in the `InsertData` component. Actually it would be better if you do the insertion login inside a service rather than the component itself, but for simplicity right now you can check the following code:

```
 InsertData = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
      return {posts: []}; // initialize the state of your component
    },

    insertToCollection(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.message + " state med message");
        var content = Posts.find().fetch();
            Posts.insert({
                Place: $("post1").val(), // better to retrieve these values from state. You can use `handleChange` method to keep track of user inputs
                Type: $("post2").val(),
                dateAdded: new Date(),
            }, function(err, data){
            var posts = this.state.posts || [];
            posts.push(data);
            this.setState({posts: posts}); //after setting the state the render method will be called again, where the updated posts will be rendered properly
            });
    },

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            message: event.target.value
        })

        console.log(this.state + " mer state her");
        function insert(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("added stuff"); 
        }
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.insertToCollection}>
                    <input type='text' placeholder="Select a restaurant" className="input-field" 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} id="post1"/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder="What type of food they have" className="input-field" 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} id="post2"/>
                    <button className="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-block" onChange={this.insert}> Submit </button>
                </form>
                <DisplayData posts={this.state.posts}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var DisplayData = React.createClass({
    render(){
        var posts = this.props.posts || [];

        var renderPosts = posts.map(function(post, index) {
            return (
              <li key={index}>{post}</li>
            ); 
        });

        return (
          <div>
            <p> Your collection </p>
            <ul>
              {renderPosts}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: running the code provided above gives me the following console output:

Comment: InsertData.jsx:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of null

Comment: I forgot to initialize the state, I updated the answer and added `getInitialState` function.

Comment: the renderPosts variable is undefined when i try to log it to the console

Comment: where do you log it? It should logan empty array initially as it is empty initially.

Comment: i open the inspect element tool, and write: console.log(renderPosts) then i get the TypeError, even after adding data to the form